# Multiple symbols replace not working

Tags: python

I need to check a string for some symbols and replace them with a whitespace. My code:

```
string = 'so\bad'

symbols = ['•', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', '\'', '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '>', '=', '?', '@', '[', ']', '\\', '^', '_', '`', '{', '}', '~', '|', '"', '⌐', '¬', '«', '»', '£', '$', '°', '§', '–', '—']

for symbol in symbols:
    string = string.replace(symbol, ' ')

print string
>> sad
```

Why does it replace a\b with nothing?

Comment: Is the intended output: "so bad"? When running your code as is the output is : "so ad".

Comment: yes, also 'so\\bad' would be 'so  bad' with 2 whitespaces

Comment: I suspect it *is* printing the `o`, however `\b` is being interpreted as a single backspace character instead of "a backslash and then a b", so when it "prints", it backs up over the previous character.

Comment: With that many symbols to replace, it might be easier to use `re.sub`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is the use of `\` as a  escape character.
`\b` is a special character (backspace)

Use a String literal with prefix `r`.
 With the `r`, backslashes `\` are treated as literal

```
string = r'so\bad'
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because `\b` is ASCII backspace character:

```
>>> string = 'so\bad'
>>> print string
sad
```

You can find it and all the other escape characters from [Python Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).

In order to get the behavior you expect escape the backslash character or use [raw strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l):

```
# Both result to 'so bad'
string = 'so\\bad'
string = r'so\bad'
```

Comment: or r'so\bad', worth mentioning IMO

Comment: @AmitGold: Thanks, modified answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You are not replacing anything "\b" is backspace, moving your cursor to the left one step.

Answer (score 0):

Note that even if you omit the `symbols` list and your `for symbol in symbols:` code, you will always get the result "sad" when you `print string`. This is because `\b` means something as an ascii character, and is being interpreted together.

Check out this stackoverflow answer for a solution on how to work around this issue: [How can I print out the string "\b" in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519914/how-can-i-print-out-the-string-b-in-python)